# Checkbox Fitlering with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering

I need your help.

I followed some tutorials to create a filterable grid with jQuery.
It's simple, the grid contains radio shows (emissions), each show has a broadcast day.
The goal was to allow visitors to select the day and the shows of the day are displayed.

The code works very well but I need to develop it further.

I added conditions to check the day and to automatically check the current day.
The problem is that when the page loads, the day is selected but the filter does not apply. I have all emissions displayed.

My goal is to :

- display the current day's broadcasts when the page is loaded
- [BONUS]: not to allow visitors to deselect the selected day. So that there is at least one day selected to not display all the shows.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var today = new Date();
  if (today.getDay() == 1) {
    $(".monday").attr("checked", "true");
  }
  if (today.getDay() == 2) {
    $(".tuesday").attr("checked", "true");
  }
  if (today.getDay() == 3) {
    $(".wednesday").attr("checked", "true");
  }
  if (today.getDay() == 4) {
    $(".thursday").attr("checked", "true");
  }
  if (today.getDay() == 5) {
    $(".friday").attr("checked", "true");
  }
  if (today.getDay() == 6) {
    $(".saturday").prop('checked', true);
  }
  if (today.getDay() == 7) {
    $(".sunday").attr("checked", "true");
  }
})

jQuery.expr[":"].CIcontains = jQuery.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
  return function(elem) {
    return jQuery(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
  };
});

jQuery('.filtre-jour input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {

  var thisID = jQuery(this).attr('id');

  jQuery('.filtre-jour input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).attr('id') != thisID) {
      jQuery(this).prop('checked', false);

    }

  })

  if (jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
    var curr_text = jQuery(this).data('search-term');
    filterResults(curr_text);
  } else {
    filterResults('');
  }

});

function filterResults(curr_text) {
  jQuery('.emission-card').hide();
  jQuery('.emission-card:CIcontains("' + curr_text + '")').show();
}
```

```html
<div class="checkboxes">
  <input id="#monday" class="monday" data-search-term="monday" type="checkbox">
  <label class="inline-checkbox" for="#monday">Lundi</label>

  <input id="#tuesday" class="tuesday" data-search-term="tuesday" type="checkbox">
  <label class="inline-checkbox" for="#tuesday">Mardi</label>

  <input id="#wednesday" class="wednesday" data-search-term="wednesday" type="checkbox">
  <label class="inline-checkbox" for="#wednesday">Mercredi</label>

  <input id="#thursday" class="thursday" data-search-term="thursday" type="checkbox">
  <label class="inline-checkbox" for="#thursday">Jeudi</label>

  <input id="#friday" class="friday" data-search-term="friday" type="checkbox">
  <label class="inline-checkbox" for="#friday">Vendredi</label>

  <input id="#saturday" class="saturday" data-search-term="saturday" type="checkbox">
  <label class="inline-checkbox" for="#saturday">Samedi</label>

  <input id="#sunday" class: "sunday" data-search-term="sunday" type="checkbox">
  <label class="inline-checkbox" for="#sunday">Dimanche</label>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to post your greed code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simplify by using the index of the checkboxes and hide those not today initially.  This should work with the corresponding card but this can be simpler than what you have on the comparison.  See second example

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  let today = new Date();
  myday = today.getDay();
  $('.day-check').eq(myday - 1).prop("checked", true);
  $('.day-card').not($('.day-card').eq(myday - 1)).hide();
})

jQuery.expr[":"].CIcontains = jQuery.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
  return function(elem) {
    return jQuery(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
  };
});

function filterResults(curr_text) {
  jQuery('.day-card').hide();
  jQuery('.day-card:CIcontains("' + curr_text + '")').show();
}

jQuery('.filtre-jour')
  .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
  .on('change', function() {
    // var thisID = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    jQuery('.filtre-jour')
      .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
      .not(this).prop('checked', false);
    if (jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
      let curr_text = jQuery(this).data('search-term');
      filterResults(curr_text);
    } else {
      filterResults('');
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filtre-jour">
  <div class="checkboxes">
    <input id="#monday" class="day-check monday" data-search-term="monday" type="checkbox">
    <label class="inline-checkbox" for="#monday">Lundi</label>

    <input id="#tuesday" class="day-check tuesday" data-search-term="tuesday" type="checkbox">
    <label class="inline-checkbox" for="#tuesday">Mardi</label>

    <input id="#wednesday" class="day-check wednesday" data-search-term="wednesday" type="checkbox">
    <label class="inline-checkbox" for="#wednesday">Mercredi</label>

    <input id="#thursday" class="day-check thursday" data-search-term="thursday" type="checkbox">
    <label class="inline-checkbox" for="#thursday">Jeudi</label>

    <input id="#friday" class="day-check friday" data-search-term="friday" type="checkbox">
    <label class="inline-checkbox" for="#friday">Vendredi</label>

    <input id="#saturday" class="day-check saturday" data-search-term="saturday" type="checkbox">
    <label class="inline-checkbox" for="#saturday">Samedi</label>

    <input id="#sunday" class="day-check sunday" data-search-term="sunday" type="checkbox">
    <label class="inline-checkbox" for="#sunday">Dimanche</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cards">
  <div class="day-card">emission-card monday</div>
  <div class="day-card">emission-card tuesday</div>
  <div class="day-card">emission-card WEDNESDAY</div>
  <div class="day-card">emission-card Thursday</div>
  <div class="day-card">emission-card friday</div>
  <div class="day-card">emission-card saturday</div>
  <div class="day-card">emission-card sunday</div>
</div>
```

Less complex

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  let today = new Date();
  let myday = today.getDay();
  $('.day-check').eq(myday - 1).prop("checked", true);
  $('.day-card').not($('.day-card').eq(myday - 1)).hide();
   $('.day-check').prop("disabled",true);
});
/* do not need if not allow changes 
function filterResults(useDay) {
  jQuery('.day-card').hide();
  jQuery('.day-card' + useDay).show();
}

jQuery('.filtre-jour')
  .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
  .on('change', function() {
    jQuery('.filtre-jour')
      .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
      .not(this).prop('checked', false);
    let term = jQuery(this).is(':checked') ? "." + jQuery(this).data('search-term') : "";
    filterResults(term);
  });
 */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filtre-jour">
  <div class="checkboxes">
    <input id="#monday" class="day-check monday" data-search-term="monday" type="checkbox">
    <label class="inline-checkbox" for="#monday">Lundi</label>

    <input id="#tuesday" class="day-check tuesday" data-search-term="tuesday" type="checkbox">
    <label class="inline-checkbox" for="#tuesday">Mardi</label>

    <input id="#wednesday" class="day-check wednesday" data-search-term="wednesday" type="checkbox">
    <label class="inline-checkbox" for="#wednesday">Mercredi</label>

    <input id="#thursday" class="day-check thursday" data-search-term="thursday" type="checkbox">
    <label class="inline-checkbox" for="#thursday">Jeudi</label>

    <input id="#friday" class="day-check friday" data-search-term="friday" type="checkbox">
    <label class="inline-checkbox" for="#friday">Vendredi</label>

    <input id="#saturday" class="day-check saturday" data-search-term="saturday" type="checkbox">
    <label class="inline-checkbox" for="#saturday">Samedi</label>

    <input id="#sunday" class="day-check sunday" data-search-term="sunday" type="checkbox">
    <label class="inline-checkbox" for="#sunday">Dimanche</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cards">
  <div class="day-card monday">Happy monday</div>
  <div class="day-card tuesday">Happy tuesday</div>
  <div class="day-card wednesday">Happy WEDNESDAY</div>
  <div class="day-card thursday">Happy Thursday</div>
  <div class="day-card friday">Happy friday</div>
  <div class="day-card saturday">Happy saturday</div>
  <div class="day-card sunday">Happy sunday</div>
</div>
```